# Has anyone ever done this before? Caching Images and showing them offline the first time they appear?

Tags: react-native, image, caching, expo, prefetch

I created an app with react native (expo) that shows a lot of product images. My customer wants the app to work 100% offline. This means that the images should all be prefetched when the app is started. You can easily solve that with Image.prefetch(uri) or the package react-native-fast-image.

But the images should be loaded from the cache memory the first time you are offline.

Or can't I at least find out the cached image URI and then specify it with Image source?

How can I achieve this?

My customer doesn't like the current solution, that you first have to see the pictures so that they come out of the cache next time.

`UPDATE:`
At the moment I'm using the `react-native-fast-image` package, so I can preload the images before displaying them later.

The problem with that, again, is that it has a limit.

It only loads the products of the first 3 markets (there are 10 markets)

So if I can increase the `FastImage preload limit`, the problem would be solved.

`UPDATE:`
Since the FastImage preload is not a promise, the preloading is still running in the background, if I wait a bit longer, more images will be prefetched, but still not every image. So there must be a limit for preloading. I just need a method to find out when the last picture is saved and how many are saved to cache.

Seems there is no callback function for preloading with FastImage.

Does anyone have an idea how to check if all images are saved?

Best regards

Showing cached Images before they even loaded once.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I solved it like this.

`Image.prefetch(uri)` to cache the images then use `Asset.fromModule(uri).localUri` to get the url from the prefetched Image.

This url can then be used as a source for Image tag.

Comment: can you show some code? i would be interested in how you accomplished this

Answer (score 0):

You can download the photos to the phone by syncing an application like Google Photos every time it connects to the internet. New photos can be downloaded to the phone by synchronizing different images as they are uploaded. In this way, it can work offline. But in the first place you have to be online and download the photos from the server.

Comment: Hi Yakup, unfortunately the problem is that my customer wants to see the pictures directly in offline mode.

Comment: Then it is necessary to put all the images in the application, but keeping all the images in the application may increase its size. Like : 

export const sources = {
  facebook: require('./facebook.png'),
  twitter: require('./twitter.png'),
  instagram: require('./instagram.png'),
};

Comment: Yes noone want's to download a 200 MB App :)

Comment: If you want to use 100% offline, you must put all the pictures in the application. How can you reduce the size of images and app size, maybe you can focus on them. Like compressing the picture and reducing the picture size.